# Failed connecting to Hive metastore: [localhost:9083]

Tags: hive, presto

Im getting error while connecting presto server to hive metastore.

Here is my hive.properties:

```
connector.name=hive-hadoop2
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://localhost:9083
hive.config.resources=/home/eweb/Downloads/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml,/home/eweb/Downloads/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml
```

And here is my hive-site.xml :

```
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.uri</name>
  <value>thrift://localhost:9083</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>

 <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
    <value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>
    <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
  </property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Demo?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
</property>


<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>root</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>password</value>
</property>
```

I have tried this in terminal :

```
bin/presto --server localhost:8080 --catalog hive --schema bookvip

presto:bookvip> SHOW SCHEMAS;
```

Is there any kind of setup error or any other error ??

Comment: Can you verify that the Thrift metastore is running on localhost port 9083? Try using `telnet localhost 9083` or `nc -v localhost 9083` to confirm.

Comment: It shows :                                                                                                         
Trying 127.0.0.2...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: Something strange is going on. `localhost` should normally point to `127.0.0.1` not `127.0.0.2`. This could explain why Presto cannot connect to it. Check your `/etc/hosts` file and fix this. Or try doing `nc -v 127.0.0.1 9083` and if that works, use `127.0.0.1` in your Presto configuration.

Comment: actually I was trying to run localhost as 127.0.0.2. I also trying with 127.0.0.1. But still it showing same error. Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: This means that the machine Presto is running on cannot access the metastore. Check your firewall rules, EC2 security groups, etc.

Comment: I got my fault. Check the answer section. Thnx for ur help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just use the following commands step by step:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 9083
```

Then kill the process using this command

```
sudo kill -s 9 processid
```

And run once again

```
hive --service metastore
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I missed to run the hive metastore service and so the error "Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server..."
To resolve, go to /usr/local/Cellar/hive/3.1.2_3/bin and run:

hive --service metastore